# How to run two java programs from bash.sh file

Tags: command-line, bash, java, jar

I need to make bash file which should run something like this:

```
cd /opt/selenium-server/

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/
```

The problem is that if I run first java -jar command is starts running process which is still running and the second java command does not run till the first process is running.

How can I run both commands so the second one starts after the first service is running? May be this is complete wrong way to run Selenium server, but I did not find anything better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `&` with a space between to both commands on the end to have them backgrounded once the execution completes. Then the script can continue once the first starts and backgrounds then exit once the second command is done doing the same.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/selenium-server/

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub &

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://173.249.58.30:4444/grid/register/ &
exit 0
```

Comment: It works, but can you tell me why is there exit command? Both java processes are running.

Comment: How else does the script to know that it is supposed to exit, if you do not tell it to do so. That tells it to exit with no error (0) because the two commands above it succeeded doing what they were supposed to do.